# ASP.NET Firebase Verify Token ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, firebase-authentication

Our users are registering using mobile phones and sms with firebase.
When they sign in, the firebase create a token id for them and we have a web page. The mobile application is sending token id with post data service.
I want to verify this token on page_load.

How can I make it the simplest way?

I tried that, but I couldn't found where I can add firebase project api etc infos.

```
using FirebaseAdmin.Auth;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.Form.Count>0 && Request.Form["token_id"]!=null)
        {
            string result = AskTokenId(Request.Form["token_id"].ToString()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }
    public static async Task<string> AskTokenId(string token_id)
    {
        try
        {
            FirebaseToken decodedToken = await FirebaseAuth.DefaultInstance.VerifyIdTokenAsync(token_id);
            string uid = decodedToken.Uid;
            return uid;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return "e";
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it.

FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance will work if you've previously initialised it.

Store the json file created from your Firebase service account in your project and use that to initialise your FirebaseApp.

```
FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.DefaultInstance;

if (firebaseApp == null)
{

   string credentials = "path-to-your-json-credentials";
   string project_id = "FirebaseProjectId";

   var keypath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(credentials);

   firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.Create(new AppOptions() { ProjectId = project_id, Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(keypath) });
}

FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.GetAuth(firebaseApp);
FirebaseToken decodedToken = await auth.VerifyIdTokenAsync(idToken);
```